# @Value Spring add empttyMap as default Value

Tags: spring

I have the below code in Spring :
private Map deviceAttributes = new HashMap<>();

Now on static analysis I get the error that I should use @Autowired,@Value,@Resource or @Inject for setting the default value .
Could someone please let me know how should I use @Value or if anyother from above can be used , please let me know . Thanks in advance , had been struggling with it from quite some time now.

Comment: Sorry, but can you show more code? With this lack of informatio nwe cannot really help...

Comment: Don't blindly follow everything that your static analysis detects. If it doesn't make sense to use one of those annotations there then don't use it.